# Making more than an event on a button

Tags: c#, events, button

Please, I want to know how to make two events on one button like: when I first click on the button display an image and while still in debugging mode the second time I click 
display another image.  What are some ways to do this?

Comment: Post some code.  We need something to work with, or something that shows you've tried to do what you're asking us to answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can make something like:

```
protected void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (Img1.Visible == false)
  {
     Img1.Visible = true;
  }
  else
  {
    Img2.Visible = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need two (or more) events to do what you want, you only need to trace how many times you clicked the button, for example using an instance variable.

```
private int clicks = 0;


 protected void myButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if(clicks == 1)
    {
        // do something
    }
    if(clicks == 2)
    {
        // do other things
    }
    if(clicks > 2)
    {
        // something else
    }

    clicks++;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this: just make sure to declare the counter outside the button

```
        int clickedCount = 0;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            clickedCount++;
            if (clickedCount % 2 == 0) { pictureBox1.ImageLocation = @"path"; } else { pictureBox1.ImageLocation = @"path"; }


        }
```

Comment: You could also use something like an if for each times clicked, or use a switch statement
if(clickedcount == 1)
if(clickedcount == 2)

Comment: `pictureBox1.ImageLocation = (++clickedCount %2 == 0) 2 ? "path1" : "path2";`

Comment: @paul Ah even shorter :) btw the 2 behind the statement won't work, it works fine without it:
pictureBox1.ImageLocation = (++clickedCount % 2 == 0) ? "path1" : "path2";